# Why are the numbers in my rep counter not adding up?

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

I wonder why my rep counter stopped adding up, even though I got some up-votes on my question. Here is my question I asked 1 hour ago: [Why do we usually use `||` not `|`, what is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101992/why-do-we-usually-use-not)

[image: +55 24 mins ago upvote Why do we usually use || not |?]

I got only 55 reps while I got 18 upvotes. Is it a bug? Or is it because I got so many reps in a short time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've hit the rep cap, basically. You can only earn a maximum of 200 rep through upvotes alone in any UTC day.

Comment: Something which happens to Mr. Skeet all too often.